# Parse.com CloudCode find Parse.User objectId with username parameter

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have created a CloudCode function that looks up the users ObjectId based off of their Username.

the result I receive are

> Ran cloud function findUserByEmail with:
>     Input: {"email":"test@email.com"}
>     Result: undefined

this is my JavaScript for the CloudCode

------------------------------------SOLUTION-----------------------------------------

```
Parse.Cloud.define("findUserByEmail", function(request, response){
   var email = request.params.email;

   if(!email) {
   response.error("Missing parameter: email");
   return ;
   }

   Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

   var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

   query.equalTo("username", email);
   query.**first**({
   success: function(user){
       var objectId = user.id;

   response.success(objectId);
   },

   error: function(error) {
       console.error(error);
       response.error("An error occured while lookup the users objectid");
   }

   });

 });
```

Not sure why my Results "Undefined"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`query.find()` returns an array of results, so `user.id` would definitely be undefined.

I'd prefer `query.first()` which returns just one.

This should work if you just change `find` to `first`.

Comment: you're my hero.  Thank you for all your help today.

Comment: or just user[0].id will also work, but better rename those variables to make sense :-)

Comment: Which variable name doesn't make sense?  (I know username is being checked but the username can only be an email address)

Comment: 'user' if using 'find' which returns an array.